# Как при наведении на div заменить его картинкой?

Tags: html, jquery, hover

Мне нужно, чтобы блок `div` при наведении на него заменялся картинкой. Когда курсор убирают с дива, то он возвращался бы назад. У меня есть наработки, но работает немного неправильно.

```js
$('.features-list li #feature-top-dev').hover(
  function() {
    $('.top-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
    $('.feature-top').css({
      'padding': '0',
      'background-color': '#f5f5f5'
    });
    $('.hover-content').fadeIn('slow');
  },
  function() {
    $('.top-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
    $('.feature-top').css({
      'padding': '20px 0',
      'background-color': '#ffea00'
    });
    $('.hover-content').fadeOut('slow');
  }
);

$('.features-list li #feature-top-design').hover(
  function() {
    $('.top-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
    $('.feature-top').css({
      'padding': '0',
      'background-color': '#f5f5f5'
    });
    $('.hover-content').fadeIn('slow');
  },
  function() {
    $('.top-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
    $('.feature-top').css({
      'padding': '20px 0',
      'background-color': '#ffea00'
    });
    $('.hover-content').fadeOut('slow');
  }
);

$('.features-list li #feature-top-graph-des').hover(
  function() {
    $('.top-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
    $('.feature-top').css({
      'padding': '0',
      'background-color': '#f5f5f5'
    });
    $('.hover-content').fadeIn('slow');
  },
  function() {
    $('.top-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
    $('.feature-top').css({
      'padding': '20px 0',
      'background-color': '#ffea00'
    });
    $('.hover-content').fadeOut('slow');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="row features-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-between justify-content-lg-center">
  <li class="col-xl-3">
    <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column bottle-text-wrapper arrow-up text-left mx-auto">
      <h3 class="features-item-header bottle-header">Redesigning With Personality</h3>
      <span class="bottle-small-text ml-auto">in <span class="yellow-text">web design</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
    <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-dev">
      <div class="top-wrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Development</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="hover-content">
        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
      <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
    <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-design">
      <div class="top-wrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Design</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="hover-content">
        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
      <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
    <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-graph-des">
      <div class="top-wrapper">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <h3 class="features-item-header">Graphic Design</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="hover-content">
        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
      <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на один из блоков с желтым фоном (Web-Dev, Web-Design, Graphic Design) он заменялся на картинку. В данный момент при наведении на любой из этих блоков картинка появляется одновременно во всех 3- блоках, мне же нужно, чтобы, например, при наведении на блок Web-Dev картинка появлялась только в нём, но не в остальных, и так же с остальными блоками.

Comment: А JQ то тебе на кой?

Comment: ну попытался так реализовать. Если можно без JQ, то буду благодарен за пример как это реализовать без него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы для каждого блока написали функции для `hover`, можно написать для всех одну вот так. И еще вы скрывали `div` и показывали картинку вот так.

```
$('.top-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
$('.feature-top').css({
  'padding': '0',
  'background-color': '#f5f5f5'
});
$('.hover-content').fadeIn('slow');
```

Но к примеру первый `$('.top-wrapper')` это не один элемент а коллекция всех 
 элементов с классом `top-wrapper` и потому `addClass('d-none')` будет для всей выбранной коллекции. В место этого нужно писать так что бы оно было только для потомка с классом `top-wrapper` для текущего элемента, у которого сработало событие. `$(this).find('.top-wrapper')`. И точно так же для всех остальных элементов с которыми делаете манипуляции.

```js
$('.features-list li>div').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find('.top-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
    $(this).css({
      'padding': '0',
      'background-color': '#f5f5f5'
    });
    $(this).find('.hover-content').fadeIn('slow');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('.top-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
    $(this).css({
      'padding': '20px 0',
      'background-color': '#ffea00'
    });
    $(this).find('.hover-content').fadeOut('slow');
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="row features-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-between justify-content-lg-center">
    <li class="col-xl-3">
        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column bottle-text-wrapper arrow-up text-left mx-auto">
            <h3 class="features-item-header bottle-header">Redesigning With Personality</h3>
            <span class="bottle-small-text ml-auto">in <span class="yellow-text">web design</span></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
        <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-dev">
            <div class="top-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Development</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hover-content">
                <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
            <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
        <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-design">
            <div class="top-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hover-content">
                <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
            <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
        <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-graph-des">
            <div class="top-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3 class="features-item-header">Graphic Design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hover-content">
                <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
            <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо за детальный ответ, всё работает как надо, но небольшая проблема в том, что перестали срабатывать эти css свойства при наведении `$(this).find('.feature-top').css({
      'padding': '0',
      'background-color': '#f5f5f5'
    });`

Comment: @Belial Просто ошибка была у меня, не заметил что `this` это уже элемент с классом `feature-top`.

Comment: теперь все срабатывает нормально, спасибо! Но появился баг, что при наведении на блок с серым фоном, тот, что под блоком с жёлтым фоном (см. скриншот) его цвет меняется на жёлтый.

Comment: а почему на jQuery делаете ? на css же это лучше будет

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Это уже спросите у автора, у него было проблема с `js`, я исправил, можете дать свой вариант ответа на `css`. Будет полезен.

Comment: @Belial Ну это уже вы делаете, можете не менять цвет.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский если подскажете как лучше на css сделать также буду благодарен.

Comment: это вариант ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KZmGaY?editors=1100

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Да конечно, а почему спрашиваете в место того что бы дать ответ здесь

Comment: @StackOverflow  лень писать ответ ... так работает и без jQuery

Answer (score 1):

А вот примерно так можно сделать все это на `css3`. А подробно об этих свойствах что написано в `css` можете прочитать в документации.

```css
.feature-top:hover>.top-wrapper{
  display: none;
}
.feature-top:not(:hover)>.top-wrapper{
  display: block; /*У вас может быть другой дисплей к примеру inline-block*/
}
.feature-top:hover{
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.feature-top:not(:hover){
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #ffea00;
}
.feature-top:not(:hover)>.hover-content{
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.feature-top:hover>.hover-content{
  -webkit-transition: visibility 1.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: visibility 1.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: visibility 1.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: visibility 1.5s ease-in-out, opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="row features-list justify-content-center justify-content-md-between justify-content-lg-center">
    <li class="col-xl-3">
        <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column bottle-text-wrapper arrow-up text-left mx-auto">
            <h3 class="features-item-header bottle-header">Redesigning With Personality</h3>
            <span class="bottle-small-text ml-auto">in <span class="yellow-text">web design</span></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
        <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-dev">
            <div class="top-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Development</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hover-content">
                <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
            <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
        <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-design">
            <div class="top-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3 class="features-item-header">Web Design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hover-content">
                <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
            <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="col-10 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 feature-item">
        <div class="feature-top" id="feature-top-graph-des">
            <div class="top-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <h3 class="features-item-header">Graphic Design</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="hover-content">
                <img src="images/features-card-img.png" alt="Bottle">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-bottom mx-auto">
            <p class="features-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper > div > div:last-child{
    background-color:#404045;
    color:#fff;
}
.image{
    height:100px;
    background-image:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYyNWnof7ef0LVGtH-i-QSDH-lPNnTRoGO4-ISUORS7HxCQOIQ");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    transition:background-image .3s;
}
.image:hover{
    background-image:url("http://www.metalsucks.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/homer-simpson-drooling-a-620x715.jpg");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="wrapper" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="text-center">
            lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="text-center">
            lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="text-center">
            lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="text-center">
           lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```